# Third-party cookies disabled on Firefox 22

Tags: facebook, firefox, cookies, google-plus

When I disable third-party cookies on Firefox, the Facebook Like and Google+ +1 buttons do not work on our site anymore.

**Aside from using 2 domains to set and check cookies, are there other ways to detect if the user has enabled/disabled third-party cookies on their browser (i.e. Firefox)?**

This would be really helpful so that the user would be notified that some features won't work because third-party cookies are disabled on the browser. Third-party cookies will be disabled by DEFAULT when Firefox rolls out this issue.

Thanks!

Comment: If a user blocks 3th party cookies he will also know the consequences. Also, if a user is logged in to Facebook or Google+ then these features will continue to work.

Comment: Third-party cookies will be disabled by DEFAULT when Firefox rolls out this issue.

Comment: The buttons also do not work even if the user is logged in.

Comment: Fear no more: http://www.pcworld.com/article/2042597/mozilla-again-postpones-firefox-thirdparty-cookieblocking-this-time-for-months.html

Comment: Best news I've read so far today! Many thanks for that info ZippyV! Safari also has the similar feature -- disable third-party cookies by default but the like buttons still work.